# How to display a Map with Employee and Multiple Addresses in Json Format

Tags: java, json

I have created two class Employee and Address and for each employee there will be multiple addresses. I would like to display those addresses in JSON format. i have tried some code below. Could you let me know how I can change my code to display the map values in the following format? Likewise I would like to display the employee with id 2.

```
{
 id: 1
 name: John
 Addresses: [
  {
   addrLine1:StreetABC Line 1
   addrLine2: StreetABC Line 2
   city:CityABC
   zip: ZipABC
  },
  {
   addrLine1:StreetXYZ Line 1
   addrLine2: StreetXYZ Line 2
   city:CityXYZ
   zip: ZipXYZ
  }
 ]
}
```

Here is the `Test.class` ;

```
import java.util.*;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Employee e1= new Employee(1,"John");
        Employee e2= new Employee(2,"Robert");

        Address a1 = new Address ("StreetABC Line 1","StreetABC Line 2", "CityABC","ZipABC");
        Address a2 = new Address ("StreetXYZ Line 1","StreetXYZ Line 2", "CityXYZ","ZipXYZ");
        Address a3 = new Address ("StreetLMN Line 1","StreetLMN Line 2", "CityLMN","ZipLMN");
        Address a4 = new Address ("StreetJQK Line 1","StreetJQK Line 2", "CityJQK","ZipJQK");

        List<Address> address1=new ArrayList<Address>();
        List<Address> address2=new ArrayList<Address>();
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);


        address1.add(a1);
        address1.add(a2);

        address2.add(a3);
        address2.add(a4);

        Map<Employee, List<Address>> employeeAddressmap=new HashMap<Employee, List<Address>>();


        employeeAddressmap.put(e1,address1);
        employeeAddressmap.put(e2,address2);

        try {
            mapper.writeValueAsString(employeeAddressmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

`Employee.class` like ;

```
class Employee{

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

`Address.class` like;

```
class Address{

    String addrLine1;
    String addrLine2;
    String city;
    String zipcode;

    public Address(String addrLine1, String addrLine2, String city, String zipcode) {
        this.addrLine1 = addrLine1;
        this.addrLine2 = addrLine2;
        this.city = city;
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }

    public String getAddrLine1() {
        return addrLine1;
    }

    public void setAddrLine1(String addrLine1) {
        this.addrLine1 = addrLine1;
    }

    public String getAddrLine2() {
        return addrLine2;
    }

    public void setAddrLine2(String addrLine2) {
        this.addrLine2 = addrLine2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getZipcode() {
        return zipcode;
    }

    public void setZipcode(String zipcode) {
        this.zipcode = zipcode;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Map add address class in your Employee model.

```
class Employee{

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Address> addresses;

    public Employee(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id=id;
    }
    public int getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    public List<Address> getAddresses()
    {
      return addresses;
    }

    public List<Address> setAddresses(List<Address> addresses)
    {
      this.addresses=addresses;
    }
}
```

Your Address class remains the same

Change your test class

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Employee e1= new Employee(1,"John");
        Employee e2= new Employee(2,"Robert");

        Address a1 = new Address ("StreetABC Line 1","StreetABC Line 2", "CityABC","ZipABC");
        Address a2 = new Address ("StreetXYZ Line 1","StreetXYZ Line 2", "CityXYZ","ZipXYZ");
        Address a3 = new Address ("StreetLMN Line 1","StreetLMN Line 2", "CityLMN","ZipLMN");
        Address a4 = new Address ("StreetJQK Line 1","StreetJQK Line 2", "CityJQK","ZipJQK");

        List<Address> address1=new ArrayList<Address>();
        List<Address> address2=new ArrayList<Address>();
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        employees.add(e1);
        employees.add(e2);


        address1.add(a1);
        address1.add(a2);

        address2.add(a3);
        address2.add(a4);


        e1.setAddresses(address1);
        e2.setAddresses(address2);

        try {
            mapper.writeValueAsString(e1);
            mapper.writeValueAsString(e2);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```